# Media library item (pdf) reachable after unpublish/not publishable

Tags: media-library, pdf

In Sitecore 9.1.1

I have some PDF documents in the media library that i've "unpublished" *(unchecked the publishable publish setting)*

Then smart-publish parent folder, subitems and all languages.

If I use the exact URL to the PDF it still downloads. I don't seem to be able to get rid of the items.
It's also still coming up on Google results.

I have...

1. confirmed that the item does NOT exist in web database.
2. deleted mediacache folder.
3. cleared cache in /admins/cache.aspx.
4. purged all cloudflare cache.
5. Rebuilt link database.
6. confirmed site definition attribute "database=web" and not master.

I'm out of ideas. What can I do next?

Thank you

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?  Browsers will grab media from cache without ever involving the server, if they think they can.

Comment: CDN cache the document?

Comment: you can also submit the url using google webmaster tools to purge the url from Google indexes

Answer (score 1):

If media is cached by Cloudflare, check cloudlare headers **cf-cache-status**, **cf-ray** when accessing media url in a browser. If the media is HIT then is still in Cloudflare cache. If you want to cache Sitecore media in CDN, you should set media to always append revision.

```
      <setting name="Media.AlwaysAppendRevision" set:value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting the URL with a random url parameter and see if it still shows up. If it does, it's coming from Sitecore. If it doesn't, it is coming from one of them caches. Most likely culprit is Cloudflare or Browser as mentioned above